# button background colour save java

Tags: java, swing, file, button

I'm working in Classes Reservation Program that tell me in Which time class available to use , so When User wants to book Class He will Click on Button  and the Background colour will Change to Red "that means its booked" but  how Can i Save the Color Changed ?

i try this

```
private void button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    File file = new File("filename.txt");
        FileWriter fw;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            Color j=button2.setBackground(Color.red);
                        bw.write();
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");


// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: and you think that reading the file will make the button red again ?? What you have to do isn't as simple as you think, the GUI is the representation of the model's state; what you have to do is to define a model that contains informations about the reservations for example and relate it to the view, which will display the state of the model. for example reserved would be a boolean in the model, before displaying the view of the component representing the reservation view will check if it's reserved (true) or not if reserved then will display it the color you want not just red.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working in Classes Reservation Program that tell me in Which time class available to use , so When User wants to book Class He will Click on Button and the Background colour will Change to Red "that means its booked" but how Can i Save the Color Changed ?

The best answer: don't.

Instead save the booking information, information that should be part of your program's overall model, and then base the button color on the state of the model, after your program loads the model. The details of this will depend on how you've structured your program, but hopefully it hews close to a Model-View-Controller type pattern, or one of its variants.